# str[0:z] works with pandas but not with modin: TypeError: 'StringMethods' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror, modin

I'm running Spyder on Python 3.7 and am new to modin. I want to retrieve the first characters in a string and save to a new column. When I run the usual with pandas it works:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('Path/data.csv', dtype=str, encoding='utf-8')
data['FL_x']=data['x'].str[0:3]
```

But when I run the same with modin I get the error: '**TypeError: 'StringMethods' object is not subscriptable'**

```
import modin.pandas as pd
#etc.
```

I can solve the problem by using str.get():

```
data['FL_x']=data['x'].str.get(0) + data['x'].str.get(1) + data['x'].str.get(2)
```

But it is very time-consuming for large amounts of data and checking many first characters.

Is there a simple way to immediately retrieve the first z characters in a string with modin as with pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try:

```
data['FL_x']=data['x'].str.slice(stop=3)
```

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot! Regular pandas is still faster than modin (with ray), but it's faster than my original solution.